# CoffeeScript Return on Functions Within Functions

Tags: javascript, meteor, coffeescript

I'm a hobbyist working through the Discover Meteor book in CoffeeScript, Jade, and Stylus (similar to [this](https://github.com/abstracthat/microscope-jade-coffeescript-stylus)).

I've come across a section of code that I cannot get to compile into proper JavaScript. My Coffee looks like this:

```
Template.postSubmit.events
 'submit form': (e) ->
   e.preventDefault()
   post =
    url: $(e.target).find('[name=url]').val()
    title: $(e.target).find('[name=title]').val()
   Meteor.call 'postInsert', post, (error,result) ->
    if error
     return alert(error.reason)
    Router.go('postPage', _id: result.id)
   return
```

It compiles to this:

```
Template.postSubmit.events({
  'submit form': function(e) {
    var post;
    e.preventDefault();
    post = {
      url: $(e.target).find('[name=url]').val(),
      title: $(e.target).find('[name=title]').val()
    };
    Meteor.call('postInsert', post, function(error, result) {
      if (error) {
        return alert(error.reason);
      }
      return Router.go('postPage', {
        _id: result.id
      });
    });
  }
});
```

According to the book, the final "return" (next to "Router.go") does not belong in the code. Everything else appears to be correct. I have tried multiple ways of re-writing my CoffeeScript with no luck. I understand that Coffee inserts a return into the last line of all functions naturally, but I've had no success with empty returns or any of the other suggestions I've seen. What I'd like to know is: will the extra return interfere with the execution of the code, and how can better write my CoffeeScript to avoid this going forward?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is with the indentation of the last `return` statement.

Here's what you have (with 4 spaces of indentation, so you can better see the differences):

```
Template.postSubmit.events
    'submit form': (e) ->
        e.preventDefault()
        post =
            url: $(e.target).find('[name=url]').val()
            title: $(e.target).find('[name=title]').val()
        Meteor.call 'postInsert', post, (error,result) ->
            if error
                return alert(error.reason)
            Router.go('postPage', _id: result.id)
        return # this is the return that is the problem
```

With the code like this, the `Router.go` is the last statement in the callback to the `Meteor.call` and therefore, the result of this expression is returned from the callback.

What you want, I think, is this:

```
Template.postSubmit.events
    'submit form': (e) ->
        e.preventDefault()
        post =
            url: $(e.target).find('[name=url]').val()
            title: $(e.target).find('[name=title]').val()
        Meteor.call 'postInsert', post, (error,result) ->
            if error
                return alert(error.reason)
            Router.go('postPage', _id: result.id)
            return # now indented farther!
```

Now the final `return` is the last statement in the callback, and it is executed after the `Router.go` statement. According to [js2.coffee](http://js2.coffee/), this fragment compiles to:

```
Template.postSubmit.events({
    'submit form': function(e) {
        var post;
        e.preventDefault();
        post = {
            url: $(e.target).find('[name=url]').val(),
            title: $(e.target).find('[name=title]').val()
        };
        return Meteor.call('postInsert', post, function(error, result) {
            if (error) {
                return alert(error.reason);
            }
            Router.go('postPage', {
                _id: result.id
            });
        });
    }
});
```

which, I think, is what you're looking for.

With respect to your other question: "will it interfere with my code?" It might. `Meteor.call` is going to call your callback when (presumably) the call is completed. It might do something with the results of the callback, so what you return from the callback might make a big difference to your application. The API for Meteor should spell out what values to return from this and other callbacks.

Comment: Perfect, indentation was indeed the issue. I had to add one more "return" to get rid of the "return" in front of "Meteor.call" but otherwise this solves it. Thank you very much.